# How can I differ between variables in SQL Tasks in a Workflow?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a task that will enter the run-id, table name and row-count into a logging table. I have 6 tables in total, and expecting 15 more tables in the next sprint.

The SQL looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO logging_rowcount (RUN_ID, tablename, row_count) values (?, 'hardcoded_name1', ?);
INSERT INTO logging_rowcount (RUN_ID, tablename, row_count) values (?, 'hardcoded_name2', ?);
```

etc, for a total of 6 INSERT INTO statements.
I mapped the parameters accordingly, using the variable "run-id" for every 2nd parameter. The task itself works, however I fear this becomes little unmaintainable when I have 21 tables (and 42 parameter mappings).

While this particular case can be solved with another loop, generally speaking:

Is there a way to use "speaking" terms for my variables? E.G.

```
INSERT INTO logging_rowcount (RUN_ID, tablename, row_count) values (@USER:run_id, @USER:tablename, @User:rowCount_table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare variables in the script task:

```
DECLARE @RunID INT = ?;

INSERT INTO .... VALUES (@RunID, ?, ...);
INSERT INTO .... VALUES (@RunID, ?, ...);
```

Now your first parameter will be the RunID and all subsequent ones are the row counts.

You can define a SQL variable in the script for all package variables if you want, so the mapping will be easier to understand (it will be in order in both the mapping and in the script, so easy to match).

You can also have the query as an expression (by having a string variable which stores the query) and in the expression you can use the parameter/variable names, but that will be prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: I like the DECLARE @RUN_ID approach, thank you! Not quite what I was hoping for, but this will definetely help down the line, as well.